# Post request secure, only my site can post to server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ssl

i want to make a Post Request to Node.js from React, but in the Developer Tool in Payload it shows me the Secret Key, and if it shows me there I haven't solved anything, is there a way for me to do this securely? and without SECRET KEY being visible in Developer Tool?

[image]

> my react post request code

```
     .post("http://.../api/test", {
          secret: process.env.REACT_APP_SECRET_KEY,
          battleData: battleData,
          accountCurent: accountCurent,
        })
        .then(function (response) {}
....
```

> and my Node.js code

```
app.post("/api/test", (req, res) => {
if(req.body.secret === process.env.REACT_APP_SECRET_KEY){}
...// I only want when Secret Key is identical by Node to the frontEnd and run my code in Node.js
```

Comment: It's not wrong for it to be inside developer tool if you are posting it on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

No, if the secret is part of the frontend a user will *always* be able to find it. Instead of solving that problem, you should try to make sure that you don't need secrets.

Answer (score 0):

i can suggest you to create a different SECERET_KEY dynamically for each user so if any user can find its own secret key it can access only within its own data and cant access unwanted data
you should learn more about Authentication and Authorisation
check passport.js

Comment: I don't use a user, I only have an account from Metamask, but I only need my website to be able to send information to Node js, I really don't know how to do that